# File timestamps precision - ext3 with nanoseconds, ext4 with milliseconds

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ext4, timestamps, ext3

People say ext3 supports file timestamp precision up to seconds and ext4 up to nanoseconds.

What happens is that my old VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 with an ext3 filesystem always (as far as I can remember) supported nanoseconds very nicely, like this:

```
  File: `auth.log'
  Size: 147744      Blocks: 304        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 800h/2048d  Inode: 32019       Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (  101/  syslog)   Gid: (    4/     adm)
Access: 2020-03-20 00:18:33.634687690 -0300
Modify: 2020-03-24 05:12:48.777610222 -0300
Change: 2020-03-24 05:12:48.777610222 -0300
 Birth: -
```

`mount` excerpt:

```
/dev/sda on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

`stat -f`:

```
  File: "auth.log"
    ID: 5483af2794a91010 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 3870084    Free: 272230     Available: 75643
Inodes: Total: 923520     Free: 829980
```

```
root@mail:~# df -mT
Filesystem     Type     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda       ext3         15118 14055       296  98% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs      1973     1      1973   1% /dev
none           tmpfs          395     1       395   1% /run
none           tmpfs            5     0         5   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs         1973     0      1973   0% /run/shm
```

---

Now, I bought a new VPS, updated it to Ubuntu 20.04 (pre-beta), it has a filesystem mounted as ext4.

```
  File: auth.log
  Size: 723967      Blocks: 1424       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca03h/51715d    Inode: 398412      Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: (  104/  syslog)   Gid: (    4/     adm)
Access: 2020-03-24 00:00:05.676000000 -0300
Modify: 2020-03-24 05:14:56.644000000 -0300
Change: 2020-03-24 05:14:56.644000000 -0300
 Birth: -
```

`mount` excerpt:

```
/dev/xvda3 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nobarrier,errors=remount-ro,stripe=32564)
```

But strangely `stat -f` says it is ext3:

```
  File: "auth.log"
    ID: 7e8a03105e52b018 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 9857995    Free: 7434726    Available: 7007355
Inodes: Total: 2505120    Free: 2403794
```

```
root@mailnew:~# df -mT
Filesystem     Type     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs       430     0       430   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs           95     2        94   2% /run
/dev/xvda3     ext4         38508  9466     27373  26% /
tmpfs          tmpfs          473     0       473   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs            5     0         5   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs          473     0       473   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs        54    54         0 100% /snap/lxd/11348
/dev/loop1     squashfs        92    92         0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/xvda1     ext4           727   183       502  27% /boot
tmpfs          tmpfs           95     0        95   0% /run/user/0
```

---

My questions are:

1. Why my old ext3 system supports nanoseconds precision?
2. Why the new ext4 is limited to milliseconds? Is it actually formatted as ext3, instead?
3. How can I figure out what is wrong and enable nanoseconds in the new one?

Comment: `stat -f` also shows `ext2/ext3` on all of my ext4 partitions

Answer (score 2):

The actual support for nanoseconds vs seconds resolution depends on the size of the inode chosen at format time. 128-byte inodes support only second resolution, 256-byte inodes support nanosecond resolution. The ext3 filesystem driver in the kernel is actually running ext4 module for many years, so it is supporting the nanosecond timestamps.

As for the millisecond-resolution timestamps, this is likely a result of the virtualization only providing a ms-resolution clock for the filesystem.

Comment: "virtualization only providing a ms-resolution clock for the filesystem" Any idea how could they fix it? What part of the virtualization software (Xen) controls that?